# Fast way of checking if my ethereum addresses can claim UNI tokens from uniswap?

Tags: metamask, uniswap, uni

I have quite a number of addresses in eth and is there a way to check if my address can claim uni without having to sign in with each individual account using uniswap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: connect a wallet (if i try this without connecting a wallet then i dont see the claim uni option , click ellipsis and you should see claim UNI option][connect a wallet to uniswap (if i try this without connecting a wallet then i dont see the claim uni option) , click ellipsis and you should see claim UNI option you can then check all of your wallet address(es) in one place  (sorry first post so not sure how to use this stack exchange interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeJv0.png)

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Take the time to improve the formatting of your answer and you will probably get upvotes. I am also deleting your comment since you can just add it to your answer.

Comment: good answer, helped me alot.